# Need guidance in implementing a third party software tool for enterprise wide organization

Tags: planning, milestones

I have been assigned to lead an implementation of a third party software tool. I would like to seek some guidance on making sure this gets implemented successfully.

I think I was asked to provide the milestones and work plans. Before I engage myself with the third party, I would like to seek some pointers and guidance on the things I should remember on how I can successfully implement a third party software tool in an enterprise organization.

Comment: Hi user, welcome to PMSE! Although the question seems to be valid, the way it stands now might sound too broad. If we consider 'implementing a third party tool' as a project, you're pretty much asking 'how to conduct a project?'. Please be more specific, highlighting the questions and problems you're facing now. You may need to split them into separated questions for the sake of clarity. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Within my business I would follow these guidelines.

- If you have access to stakeholders such as department managers, swing them in for a quick chat to make sure the roll-out will be supported. If you can't chat one on one or you need to approach a number of stakeholders, have a quick kick off meeting. If they don't buy in, your software solution is probably going to fail.
- This goes for the end user too. As a quick example, we installed Lync IM on our computer clients for Customer Service reps. It was free so no loss besides the configuration time, but at the end of the day, it was easier to email someone else than send them an instant message. Have you trialed the software? If not, run a trial. 
  -Make sure integration won't be an issue, eg check with your systems guys to make sure the services can run on your it equipment, no use going to roll out and finding out you need to get firewall rules written up for it. This especially goes for BI tools. If you can't access the database, don't bother. 
  -As far as milestones go, I would aim for Cost Analysis, Kick-Off meeting, Trial Roll-out, Sign-off approval with stakeholders, Create Training package, roll out across system, and monitor and control.

  This is general, however the best advice I can give is manage everyone's expectations about why they need the system, what it does, how they can use it, and when they can use it. Lastly, if it's not working, make sure you let the project sponsor know. There are plenty of good PM documents online, have a look around